# Raw socket for directing IPv6 datagrams to the kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, ipv6, raw-sockets

I’m looking to inject IPv6 datagrams available in the user space (and received through a  scheme that first requires some unwrapping that's performed in the user space)  to a suitable raw socket for further processing by the Linux kernel. This is fairly simple to do with IPv4 using the following code:

```
    int fd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
    struct sockaddr_ll sa;
    memset(sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    // ip4h is the IPv4 datagram unwrapped in the user space and ready to be 
    // sent to the kernel
    if (sendto(fd, iph, iplen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa)) != iplen) {
       // Error processing.
    }
```

The above injects full IPv4 packets (including the IPv4 headers), and the IPv4 payload gets processed appropriately by the Linux stack. How should the above be modified for use with IPv6 packets? The following adjustments I tried did not work:

```
int fd=socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
sa.sll_family=AF_PACKET;
sa.sll_protocol=htons(ETH_P_IPV6);
sa.sll_halen=ETH_ALEN;
sa.sll_ifindex=2; // <index of eth0>
if (sendto(fd, iph, iplen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa)) != iplen) {
       // Error processing.
}
```

Any thoughts on why the above doesn't work with raw IPv6 datagrams? 'tcpdump ip6' does show the IPv6 packets I'm inserting, which suggests the kernel sees them! It just happens to be ignoring them as well.

Comment: Why change protocols?  You just want AF_INET6 and sockaddr_in6

Comment: @stark: Yes, AF_INET6/SOCK_DGRAM along with sockaddr_in6 was tried but did not make a difference. An example would certainly help if you had success with it.

Comment: I think you should use a Linux tun/tap device instead of a raw socket. It is more suitable in this situation.